# Django Filer getting 'thumbnail' is not a valid tag library error to do with ImageChop

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-filer

I have just installed Django-filer following the instructions on the Github page. I am running django 1.4.5 on python 2.7

Some parts of the Settings.py for my app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cms', 
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    #'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'filer',
    'mptt',
    'cmsplugin_nivoslider',
    #'sorl.thumbnail',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'cmsplugin_nivoslider.thumbnail_processors.pad_image',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters',
)
```

You may have noticed I am trying to get the nivoslider to work too. (The real reason of having Django-filer although I think it would be useful anyway.)

I am a relative newbie with Django-CMS but everyone else is saying that this is usually because you haven't installed easy_thumbnail in the installed apps. I have and have run the syncdb command (several times)

I am a little at a loss here and would appreciate any help that is available.

Comment: So, you are saying that if you remove `filer` from `INSTALLED_APPS`, an error `'thumbnail' is not a valid tag library` goes away?

Comment: Well, if I removed filer from the installed_apps, would I still be able to click to add a folder in the admin of the site?

Comment: your `settings.py` seems OK, clearly something else is wrong. First step to determine what is wrong is to understand the problem, which didn't appear magically out of nowhere. You are hinting, that the error appeared **after** you added filer to `INSTALLED_APS`. So, if you remove it from `INSTALLED_APS`, error goes away, am I right?

Comment: I know how trial/error works. The folders is something that is added when you install django-filer. If filer is taken out the error goes away because you can no longer add folders in the admin. It's not a fix at all.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get is about a missing template tag library so syncdb is not going to help. Uncommenting sorl.thumbnails in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS (or removing any reference to the 'thumbnails' tags lib from your templates if you don't use this lib) is more likely to solve the problem.

[edit]
The `thumbnail` templatetags lib is supposed to be provided by easy_thumbnails, which you do have in your installed_apps - IOW it should JustWork. Either there's something broken in your install or, well, I don't know. Could you try to import the `thumbnail` module from your django shell and see if you get a better traceback ?

```
# from easy_thumbnails.templatetags import thumbnail
```

[/edit]

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. The sorl.thumbnails was added after the error message as part of my trying to get it work. It makes no difference if it is there or not. The template that is throwing the error is the default template in filer. I haven't set any it is the admin page to add folders in django filer :-(

Comment: Uh ok I thought you removed it while adding filer or easy_thumbnails. Anyway

Comment: @DanielCasserly : I edited my (erroneous) answer, can you try what I suggest and post the results ?

Comment: The error is the same that there is no module named imagechops

Comment: @DanielCasserly : that's not "the same error" - or you didn't report the whole error the first time. Could you please post the _full_ traceback ?